# Dynamically showing images in a card rendered using a html template not showing images correctly

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display some information on my web page using the `json` data that i am getting from the server but the images are not getting displayed correctly on the respective cards.

This is the class which is being converted to Json and sent to the browser.

```
public class AgendaViewModel
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<string> _standardSpeakers;
    public List<string> StandardSpeakers { get { return _standardSpeakers ?? (_standardSpeakers = new List<string>()); } set { _standardSpeakers = value; } }

}
```

Basically I created a sample card as displayed in screen shot below and then created a template of this card so that dynamically i can repeat/display this card for all the agenda items that are returned from the server. Here is the HTML code including the template for the card.

```
<section>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class='row card-list'>
            @*Agenda will be added here dynamically using AJAX call.*@
        </div>

        <template id="keynote-speaker-card">
            <li><a href=""><img class="speakerImg1" /></a></li>
        </template>

        <template id="agenda-card">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-12">
                <div class="main card">
                    <div class="card-header-1 pt-20">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <h6 class="sessionDate"></h6>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ecebeb;">
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-12">
                                <div class="row ">
                                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-12">
                                        <h6 class="sessionTime"></h6>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-10 col-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-12">
                                        <h4 class="sessionTitle "></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-12 mt-10">
                                        <h5 class="mb-20">Speakers</h5>
                                        <h6 class="keynoteHeading" style="display:none">Keynote:</h6>
                                        <ul class="custom-ul-image">
                                            <div id="img0" class="keynote-speakers-list">
                                            </div>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>

    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the Ajax call which is being sent to the server to get the data in Json format.

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $('.card-list').html("");
        var data = $('#searchForm').serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAgenda", "Agenda")',
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                response.search.Results.forEach(function (ele) {
                    var card = $($('#agenda-card').html());
                    card.find('.sessionDate').text(ele.Date);
                    card.find('.sessionTime').text(ele.Time);
                    card.find('.sessionTitle').text(ele.Title);
                    ele.StandardSpeakers.forEach(function (speaker) {
                        var keynoteSpeakerCard = $($('#keynote-speaker-card').html());
                        keynoteSpeakerCard.find('.speakerImg1').attr('src', speaker);
                        $('#img0.keynote-speakers-list').append(keynoteSpeakerCard);
                    });
                    $('.card-list').append(card);
                });
            },
        });
    });
```

Server is returning the data in correct format and order, but when I display this data using the above Ajax's success code, the Keynote Speaker's images are not correctly reflecting on the right cards i.e. most of the cards are showing same image. I think this has something to do with the class, which is rendering images even for cards to which the image does not belong.

here is a sample card, which is supposed to display images (s) for respective session (actual image hidden in the picture intentionally)

[image]

Comment: Image url correct?

Comment: yes, image URLs are perfectly fine.. some cards don't have images in database, some have 1, some have 2 or more.. but most of the cards are showing same images..

Comment: $('#img0.keynote-speakers-list').append(img); where you declared img variable?

Comment: @vadivela i'm so  sorry, that was a typo while preparing/refactoring code for posting online... updated that part now.